# How to add own data to POST in YII2?

Tags: ajax, database, forms, activerecord, yii2

i've question about adding some data outside form and send it with form data. Look! I have 3 fields ActiveForm:

name (text)
email (email)
course (hidden)

Ok, but i need to add one more named "status". I do not want to add hidden fields, just want to add inside controller or model.

How?

Controller:

```
public function actionFree()
{
    $model = new SubscribeForm();

    $this->view->title = "ШКОЛА ПИСАТЕЛЬСКОГО МАСТЕРСТВА: Новичок курс";

    if ($post = $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Данные приняты');
            return $this->refresh();
        }
        else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка');
        }
    }
    else {
        // страница отображается первый раз
        return $this->render('free-course', ['model' => $model, 'course_id' => 1]);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class SubscribeForm extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $fio;
    public $email;
    public $course;
    public $status;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['fio', 'email'], 'required'],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'safe']
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: you have already decalared  a field named status in your model  .. so just use it ..  `$model->status =  'your_status';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the value in your controller, like this:

```
public function actionFree()
{
    $model = new SubscribeForm();
    $model->status = 'your-status-value';
    // ... the rest of your code
```

Or you could add a default value in your model. This way you can still overrule the value from the controller or a form field, but will get this value when nothing else is supplied.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => 'your-default-status-value'],
        // .. other rules
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have error. I used second method for default variable, but want to send $course. Look:
Inside controller:
$model = new SubscribeForm();
$model->course = 1;
//...

And inside model:
public $course = 0;
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
//...
            ['course', 'default', 'value' => $this->course],
        ];
    }

The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `users` (`fio`, `email`, `status`) VALUES ('ASDASDA.', 'email@yandex.ru1', 1).

Nothing about course, why?

Comment: Are you sure the column `course` exists in your table? Otherwise it will definitely not show up in the SQL. Also, it does not make sense to create variables for your columns. This is what ActiveRecord already does for you in the background. So you don't need the `public` variables. And the rule for the course value also doesn't make sense because you're setting it to the value it already has.

Comment: I have "course" column in users. Course value i do not want to send from form. I want to set it in back. But i have this error. 

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`***`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`course`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Sounds like the value you're trying to save in the course column does not exist yet in the courses table. If you want save the value 1 to the course column there should first exist a record in the courses table with id 1.

Comment: Ok, lets try without indexes... Look, i have rules:

`public $status, $course;
[['fio', 'email'], 'required'],
['email', 'email'],
[['status', 'course'], 'safe'],`

And inside controller:
`$model = new SubscribeForm();
        $model->course = '2';
        $model->status = '3';

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($model->save()) {`

In db: FIO and EMAIL are values, but status and course - not. Why?

status and course - INT

Comment: Done! I remove variable on model :D